# How would i remove a while function from my python code and turn it into a recursive function instead?

Tags: python, recursion, wildcard

I need to write a python code that contains a recursive function called ‘match(pattern, word)’, that can be used to determine if a given pattern matches a given
word. A pattern consists of letters and ‘?’ wildcards. A ‘?’ wildcard matches any letter at the corresponding position in the word. We were given these hints and are not allowed to use 'for' or 'while' loops:

- When the wildcard character ‘?’ appears in a pattern it indicates that any letter may
  appear at that position.
- I can think of three base cases. One is when both strings are empty. Another is when
  one is empty and the other is not. And the third is …
- The palindrome function makes progress by ‘eating’ the characters at the ends of the
  string. This function makes progress by eating the first letter of each string

I am new to recursion and am not entirely sure how to code for it. i have included the code I have written so far but am not sure how to write it without the while function.

```
#function to match a pattern with a word
def match(pattern, word):
   #if the length of pattern and word are 0 return true
   if(len(pattern) == 0 and len(word) == 0):
      return True
   #if the lenght of pattern and word are not equal return false
   elif(len(pattern) != len(word)):
      return False
   else:
      #if the current letter is not a wild card and the letter are not equal return false
      if(pattern[0] != '?' and pattern[0] != word[0]):
         return False
      else:
         #call the function with rest of the pattern and rest of the word
         return match(pattern[1:], word[1:])
#prompt the user to enter a pattern
pattern = input("Enter a pattern (or q to quit):\n")
#iterate until the user enters q
while(pattern != 'q'):
   #prompt the user to enter a word
   word = input("Enter a word:\n")
   #check whether the pattern matches a word or not and displat the message
   if(match(pattern, word)):
      print("It's a match")
   else:
      print("They don't match")
   #prompt the user again
   pattern = input("Enter a pattern (or q to quit):\n")
```

here is the input and output that should be produced:

```
Enter a pattern (or 'q' to quit):
l?ad
Enter a word
lead
It's a match.
Enter a pattern:
le?d
Enter a word
led
They don't match.
Enter a pattern (or 'q' to quit):
l??d
Enter a word
lend
It's a match.
Enter a pattern (or 'q' to quit):
q
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `match` function seems good to me. You can also make the user prompt recursive:

```py
def prompt():
    pattern = input("Enter a pattern (or q to quit):\n")
    if pattern!='q':
        word = input("Enter a word:\n")
        if(match(pattern, word)):
            print("It's a match")
        else:
            print("They don't match")
        prompt()
```

Comment: i have implemented what you siad to change. BUt when i try to run the code, I'm prompted to 'Enter a pattern' and after entering a pattern such as l?ad, instead of then saying 'Enter a word' , the code then does nothing after

Comment: Make sure your indentations are correct, I've tested it and it should work. You should also check @ninjagecko's answer which will help you understand how to do this on your own next time :)

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is basically two parts: The first part is "how do you do this recursively?" which is the question you meant to ask, and the second part is the direct answer to the general question you asked, which is (one way) to in general convert imperative to recursive without using most basic primitives (in this case I mostly used pure recursion).)

---

### Part 1 - your particular problem

In general the hint for recursion is that it is very well suited for problem with similar structure. The similar structure here is that if a substring matches, then you can use that solution (assume you know the answer) recursively to solve a bigger problem:

```
def match(pattern,text):
  # maybe fill in base case
  return match(pattern,text[:1]) and #fill me in
```

```
potatoes
potato?s

potatoe
potato?s

potato
potato?s

potat
potato?s

pota
potato?s

...

p
potato?s
```

Alternatively:

```
def match(pattern,text):
  #fill me in maybe
  return match(pattern,text[1:]) and #fill me in
```

```
potatoes
potato?s

 otatoes
potato?s

  tatoes
potato?s

   atoes
potato?s

...

       s
potato?s
```

You don't actually need to slice the string down each time because that's grossly inefficient... you just need to pass in the index you want to work with, then do `text[n]`.

Sometimes it helps to write a helper function that gets at the core of how you're recursing:

```
def match(pattern, text):
  '''Whether pattern matches the entirety of text char-by-char, except '?' may be any char'''
  
  # some code here
  
  def prefixesMatch(upToLength):
    if upToLength==0:
      return True
    else:
      p = pattern[upToLength-1]  #maybe rename upThroughIndex to avoid -1
      t = pattern[upToLength-1]
      return prefixesMatch(upToLength-1) and (#etc)

  # some code here
```

---

The rest of the answer mentions how to directly translate a while and for loop. However, when programming recursively, you wouldn't really think about while and for loops, so it may be bad for you to read it.

---

### Part 2 - imperative to recursive with minimal primitives

Stop. Don't read the answer. Imagine the call tree: every function calls another function, and if you imagine all the function calls, the functions are called in a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure)-like manner.

So normally when we want to repeat something, we use a repeat-type construct like a for or while loop. This code exists in some function block somewhere. This will allow a single function to call a bunch of code like this:

```
some func
   loop iter 1, return
   loop iter 2, return
   loop iter 3, return
return
```

The above looks like a root with 3 children. Now imagine we had no such primitives; no while or for loops... naively then any call would chain like so:

```
some func
   loop iter 1,
      loop iter 2,
         ...
      return
   return
return
```

The above looks like a chain of length 3 from a great-great-grandparent root node.

---

The answer:

If you still can't figure it out, the general idea is as follows:

```
while(breakIfFalse()) {
  doStuff();
}
```

Read up on the exact definition of a while loop. It does the test, then if the test passes, it does the stuff, then repeats. (Not to be confused with a do-while loop, which first does stuff, then does the test to see if it should repeat.)

```
function whileLoop(breakIfFalse, doStuff) {
  if (!breakIfFalse())
    whileLoop(breakIfFalse, doStuff);
}
```

The above is poor form because it is not function and side-effect free: to properly do this, you'd pass all the global state, declaring the state as a function parameter (such as a dictionary, or multiple parameters), and plumbing them through as extra arguments.

The for-loop is slightly more complicated merely because the definition of a for loop is slightly more complicated, and left as an exercise to the reader. Recall the definition of the for-loop: `for(init; cond; update){stuff}` is init then `if (cond) {stuff; update; repeat this}`

---

(sidenote: a while loop is common, but really a better construct that is a lot more useful is just an infinitely loop that you can break out of at any point in time; you'd simulate this with doStuff1() then test() then doStuff2(), or even better...)

```
class LoopBreak(Exception):
  pass

def _breakOutOfLoop():  # could be defined inside the next function...
  raise LoopBreak()

def breakableInfiniteLoop(doStuff, state):
  try:
    doStuff(state, _breakOutOfLoop)
    breakableInfiniteLoop(doStuff, state)
  except LoopBreak as ex:
    return

def myDoStuff(state, breakContinuation):
  text = input("Enter solution to 1+1:")
  if text=='2':
    breakContinuation()
  print('Try again...')

breakableInfiniteLoop(myDoStuff, {'numWrongGuesses':0})
```

In the above I use inversion of control, where the doStuff() is in charge of when to break out of the loop... but we could have just done it traditionally where we pass in a doStuff() AND a testToBreak() function to the loop combinator. In the latter case, the loop combinator would have to be responsible for passing state back and forth between the two coroutines.

---

If you did this 1000000 times then Python would barf at you, because it will automatically detect you've recursed 1mil+ times and wonder if you're in an infinite loop. You can increase this limit with some variable in the `sys` module, but fundamentally you have the problem "why do we really need to do this giant chain in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)?" (best to google image search what it is... unless you play Magic the Gathering in which case you know exactly what it is).

```
some func
   loop iter 1,
      loop iter 2,
         ...
            ...
               ...
                   1mil later . . .
                         ...
                             why have we used
                            so much memory?
             ...                        
          ...
      return
   return
return
```

Normally if you were trying to do this in a language, you would use something called a trampoline, which basically takes a function that immediate evaluates it to get a "the rest of the computation" result... which is some new function to immediately evaluate to get another "remaining work to do in the form of a function" result, over and over again.

(Tail call optimization is I think a special case of trampolining, but I may be wrong here.)

So anyway what you really want to do is write in continuation passing style... which is a graduate-level concept, but kind of solves everything ever. Compilers are written in CPS. It is basically just putting a callback for every function. (Javascript has a very fake and less powerful version of this with thenables/Promises but the idea is the same. Anyway you can do this in almost any language.)

Rather that directly calling the callback, we trampoline-ify it and return a function (or an object containing a function) we will immediately invoke. This is CPS without trampolining. I do not show the `state` argument for clarity:

```
def infiniteLoop_Cps(loopIter, callback_doneWhile):
  loopIter(callback_doneWhile)
  infiniteLoop_Cps(loopIter, callback_doneWhile)

def myLoopIter(callback_doneIter):
  text = input("Enter solution to 1+1:")
  if text=='2':
    callback_doneIter()
  print('Try again...')

def onBreak():
  raise Exception()

infiniteLoop_Cps(myLoopIter, onBreak)
```

Normally you wouldn't use an Exception in this kind of style, but it is useful pedantically because it shows you where in the stack you were. Here notice how the call tree is a 4-length chain:

```
>>> infiniteLoop_Cps(myLoopIter, onBreak)
Enter solution to 1+1:6
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:4
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:8
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in infiniteLoop_Cps
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in infiniteLoop_Cps
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in infiniteLoop_Cps
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in infiniteLoop_Cps
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myLoopIter
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in onBreak
Exception
```

This would be with trampolining, and avoids the 4-length chain:

```
def trampoline(getRestOfComputation):
  while True:
    getRestOfComputation = getRestOfComputation()

def infiniteLoop_CpsTramp(loopIter, callback_doneWhile):
  def runOnceThenCheckAgain():
    loopIter(callback_doneWhile)
    return infiniteLoop_CpsTramp(loopIter, callback_doneWhile)
  return runOnceThenCheckAgain

def myLoopIter(callback_doneIter):
  text = input("Enter solution to 1+1:")
  if text=='2':
    callback_doneIter()
  print('Try again...')

def onBreak():
  raise Exception()

trampoline(infiniteLoop_CpsTramp(myLoopIter, onBreak))
```

```
>>> trampoline(infiniteLoop_CpsTramp(myLoopIter, onBreak))
Enter solution to 1+1:6
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:4
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:8
Try again...
Enter solution to 1+1:2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in trampoline
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in runOnceThenCheckAgain
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myLoopIter
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in onBreak
```

Yes, we cheated a bit by using a single `while` in the trampoline mechanism itself. I believe one can avoid it by using the Y-combinator.